# Record HTTPS requests of a mobile IOS/Android application with JMeter

Tags: performance, https, jmeter

Is it possible to record httpS requests of a native app (IOS or Android) with JMeter? I tried some ways that I found but, I've not resolved the problem..

Comment: and what are those unuseful ways?

Comment: When I did proxy on Ios device, jmeter recorded http but not https.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jmeter 3 with Java 7 or 8, it creates a crt file in jmeter/bin folder. It is the CA that creates the certificates.

Send this file by mail and open it in Android / iOS then install it.

In test script recorder, put in the dedicated field HTTPS domains , the domains you are trying to hit, see:

-http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder

Restart Ipad/Android and jmeter test script recorder and try again.

Comment: Thanks for reply but I couldn't install the certificate. When I click the certificate from mail on mobile device, nothing happen. Could you give me more detail about it?

Comment: It has done. When I open the certificate from mail app, couldn't be installed but when I open it from browser, it could be installed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

to do this, you have to make your device trust the Jmeter Proxy CA.
So, you have to import the Jmeter CA certificate from

$JmeterHome/bin/ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt

into the device.
I remember this is an area where things improved a lot recently, so be sure to have the last version installed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try deleting `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt`, JMeter's self-signed certificates have very limited life time (I recall something like 1 week), so if your certificate is older you might have problems installing it into browsers and/or mobile devices or it won't decrypt SSL traffic. The file will be re-created next time you start [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
2. There is an alternative way of recording the mobile traffic by using your personal cloud proxy. Moreover, it will perform automatic correlation for you so you won't have to worry not only about SSL certificates, but also about Regular Expression extractor, JMeter Variables, etc. Check out [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) article for details.

If none of the above helps, take the following troubleshooting steps:

1. Add [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener as a child of the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder. In case of any problems with the recording a request it should display the error details.
2. Check your mobile device logs during failed certificate installation attempt. You may need to install Android and iOS developer tools for this.
3. Make sure that your application is **really** uses HTTP or HTTPS protocols as JMeter supports only these 2.